# [Typescript]: Is it possible to create typesafe Map with key of generic X and value of generic X?

Tags: typescript, generics

desired behaviour is:

```
const obj: ??? = {
  [Fruit<T>]: Taste<T>,
  [Fruit<Y>]: Taste<Y>,
}

const key: Fruit<T> = ...;

obj[key] // can only be Taste<T>
```

I understand that I can use something like `Record<Fruit<T>, Taste<T>>` but it would still allow me to set `Taste<T>` for `Fruit<Y>`;

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to have a map type that represents what `Fruit` is associated with which `Taste`, something like

```js
type FruitTasteMap = {
    apple: 'yummy'
    banana: 'not so much'
}
```

your object would then be typed as

```js
type F = {
    [k in keyof FruitTasteMap]: FruitTasteMap[k]
}
```

which results in exactly what you are looking for

```js
const ok: F = { // OK
  apple: 'yummy',
  banana: 'not so much'
}

const wrong: F = {
  apple: 'yummy',
  banana: 'like it!' // Type '"like it!"' is not assignable to type '"not so much"'
}
```